# Flash memory programming over CAN bus

Tags: bootloader, can-bus

I am planning a project using three different uC: [ATSAMC21N18](http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/SAMC20_C21_%20Family_Data_%20Sheet_DS60001479D.pdf), [PIC18F4548](http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/devicedoc/39625c.pdf) and a motor driver (not yet chosen). In total there will be 20-30 PCBs many of them are the same kind with the same firmware. For the main communication between the µC I have chosen CAN.

Usually, I flash the uC using a PICKIT with MPLab but with constant revisions and that many uC I am wondering if it is possible to flash the individual uC using CAN?

From my experience with the Arduino, it has a bootloader that enables the UART communication.

Can I include a bootloader that enables CAN on my chips? Do I have to write them myself? Are there existing tools to enable some functionality and write a bootloader to the chip?

I am unable to find literature on this topic.

Comment: SAM C21 supposedly has a special part number with bootloader pre-programmed on-chip. What interface it uses or how it works, I have no idea. Writing your own multidrop CAN protocol for the purpose of updating flash is certainly possible, but lots of work both on firmware side and PC side. Most importantly, you have to design a "safe mode" for the whole system where you allow re-programming, because re-programming MCUs during live operation is sheer madness, regardless of what the application is doing.

Comment: Has this 'safe-mode' programming a designated name? I want to read up on how difficult it would be

Comment: No designated name, it is simply good practise when designing embedded systems. For example the CANopen standard has a "pre-operational" mode where it allows configuration messages. Soon as it goes operational, those messages are no longer allowed.

Comment: Basically, to implement this you need flash programming drivers & CAN bus drivers on all MCUs. You need to invent a higher level protocol suitable for data transfers (look at CANopen SDO for inspiration). You need some means to give each MCU an unique node id through hardware, then have the CAN protocol use this node id. You need the mentioned safe vs operational modes. You need a PC program that can send this protocol and convert from your binary format to the protocol format. I've designed things like this in the past, I'd estimate it to ~6 months work if you also have to write the drivers.

Comment: (This assuming that you know enough of CAN, microcontroller programming and PC programming, and that someone else makes the hardware.)

Comment: The standard way to flash over CAN, would be to use `Unified Diagnostic Services` (UDS) or `Universal Measurement and Calibration Protocol` (XCP), each one have a section about flashing.